# About error-page in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I configure my `error-page` in `web.xml`，for example: `<error-page><error-code>404</error-code><location>/error.jsp</location></error-page>。`

If I put a URL in browser that does not exits such as `http: //localhost:8080/mywebsite/a` , it will display the contents of `error.jsp`.But the `URL` in `browser` is not `http: //localhost:8080/mywebsite/error.jsp` , it is still `http: //localhost:8080/mywebsite/a` why ? And what to do if make the URL to be `error.jsp`?

I ask this because I scan this URL using IBM AppScan, it says response status is 200 OK.

Comment: Please edit in information about the Application Server and possibly Portal/Frameworks which you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in re-writing the URL to show the user that he/she has hit the error page. In-fact it may expose the structure of your application that may be harmful if you are not too careful.

`http://yourhost/something/invalid/url` is not much helpful for any malicious user.

But

`http://yourhost/pages/errorPages/404Page.jsp`

exposes a lot of critical information to the user about the structure of your web-application.

Comment: OK,Thank you.But why does AppScan says it is not security?

Comment: Which container are you using and exactly which version?

Comment: Weblogic Server, the version is 9.2.